# convert char array to integer value and add them

Tags: c, linux

How can I extract numbers from a char array, separated with spaces, convert them to integers and sum them? For example:

```
"34 54 3 23"
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the result to be `3454323` or `114`?

Comment: @randy: Click "faq" at the top of any StackOverflow page.

Comment: @randy: Tomalak means that you've asked 13 questions, at least 10 of which have a few upvoted answers, but you've not "accepted" any of them as "the answer that most helpful to you" (i.e. clicked on the big arrow to the left of the answer). People are more likely to help if they see that you appreciate their help.

Comment: @randy: Also this looks rather like a homework type question: If it is, it should be tagged as such so that we can help you appropriately ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework

Comment: @zhaph sir:ok from now on i  i will defiantly accept the answers. srory i didnt know about it thanks for telling. kindly tell me i want ot vote up the answer but it is asking for open ID what is that how to get it

Comment: @randy: OpenID is a way that you can provide authentication credentials from a known provider to other sites - You may find that you already have one if you've got an account on Google (i.e. Gmail, YouTube), Facebook, Yahoo (i.e. Flickr, etc), there's lots more details on the Login Page (http://stackoverflow.com/users/login) including links to the OpenId Foundation with more details: http://openid.net/what/

Answer (score 2):

I'd start at the beginning of the array, check each character in turn with `isdigit()` and keep a current value and a current total.
When reaching the terminating NUL char (or last element of the array), the current total is already calculated.

Comment: sir i am using c programming there is no isdigit function

Comment: [isdigit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isdigit.html) is described in the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (PDF version) in paragraph 7.4.1.5 (page 194).

Comment: The C89 Standard I have, describes `isdigit` in paragraph 4.3.1.4. My copy of [K&R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131103628) indexes it for pages 166 and 249.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string.

If you know how many integers are in there, you could use just a `sscanf`.

Otherwise find out where blanks are (with something **similar** to `strtok`, for example) and then read integers using `atoi`

Comment: `atoi()` is very unfriendly when things go wrong. Better to use `strtol()` :)